# Cannot install in Kepler due to org.junit4 dependency

Tags: eclipse, javafx-2

I have found this but I don't know which manifest file is meant.
"The fix for this is simply to replace org.junit4 with org.junit in the manifests."

http://efxclipse.org/trac/ticket/332

Could you please guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For kepler you need to use http://downloads.efxclipse.org/eclipse.org/p2-repos/ide/nightly/ or use the prepackaged distros http://downloads.efxclipse.org/eclipse.org/sdks/nightly/